# Why is const illegal in a switch case statement?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why is const not allowed in a case block inside a switch?

This will generate a JS error:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    const foo = "bar";
    switch (foo) {
        case "bar":
            const bar = "foo"; // error
            console.log("bar is", bar);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("nope");
            break;
    }
}());
```

But this works:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    const foo = "bar";
    switch (foo) {
        case "bar":
            var bar = "foo"; // error
            console.log("bar is", bar);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("nope");
            break;
    }
}());
```

I've been going through the ECMASCript specification and it doesn't jump out at me why this isn't allowed. `const` is allowed in a `LexicalEnvironment`. Is a case block a special kind of block of JavaScript? Or is this an error?

**Edit**:

This was a bug in Chrome 42. Updating to Chrome 43 fixed it.

Comment: both codes looks the same...

Comment: The first uses `const bar` the second `var bar`. Did you run them with web inspector open?

Comment: Your first example works for me (in Firefox 37). What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome. I haven't tried firefox. Will try now.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 43.0.2357.124 m

Comment: First example worked for me in Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit)). Which version are you using?

Comment: Both work on my machine, I am using Chrome 43.0.2357.124 m.

Comment: Did you post **the exact code** you tested?

Comment: 1st one doesn't work for me too (Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 m)

Comment: Did you post **the exact error message** you received?

Comment: I had an update pending, just upgraded to 43 and now both work. Looks like this was a bug!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what was the error?

Comment: "Unexpected token const"

Comment: Unexpected token error. My jsx-loader still has trouble building it actually.

Comment: And why exactly are you doing a switch on a constant value?  You know what the value is already, you don't have to have any kind of conditional statement.

Comment: This was just a reduced set of code to demonstrate the problem. This is not actual code from my application. I use const instead of var or let for "variables" that I expect should never change.

Answer (score -4):

**The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment**, and a constant cannot be re-declared.

You can see more details about const from MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Where do you see reassignment happening in this code? That's not the problem here.

Comment: Sorry, I checked again. Both these 2 code snippets run perfect on my machine. My browser is Chrome 44.0.2403.18 beta-m (64-bit).